How do I smoothly play sheets that require two notes to be played simultaneously?
I am not very experienced in playing the guitar, and most of the sheet music I have learned to play smoothly requires me to play one note at a time. However, I have tried to play the following notes and spent several hours on it, but I still cannot play it smoothly, fast enough.

The problem is that whenever I get to the part where I have to play two notes at the same time, I pause a little. I'm wondering if this is normal, and the problem can be solved by practicing consistently every day and my speed would automatically increase. Or if there are some exercises that can help me play these parts faster.

I want to make sure you’re aware that this music is written to be played classical style, with plucking hand thumb opposed by index middle and ring fingers. Many people bypass things like method books because of the sheer volume of free online content available but they are very useful for building up the skill required for playing this type of piece.

A lot of music will take several weeks to several months to learn, so I would get concerned when it’s only been several hours.

Well - any time you do something more complex than what you've been used to so far, you'll find that it doesn't go perfectly from the start. So I'd say it's totally normal. And practice is always at least part of the answer.
You may have already been doing this, but it's possible you didn't need it yet: One thing you can sometimes do is figure out chords. For instance, the first full bar will be easiest to play if you hold the Ami chord (the good old open version of it) and only add or lift a finger for the out-of-chord tones. This isn't an option you have always, but if you can find a position in which you can hold your left hand without moving it much for a while, it makes things easier than shifting the hand before each note again.

On the assumption that you can play the single line of melody in time, I don't see the problem. All of the 'double' notes (at the start of each bar) have an open string as the lower one, so will be played by thumb. That thumb could even be resting on the appropriate string in advance, so when the next bar arrives, it's exactly in place. No need to even think about where the thumb should go!
The other double notes are all on adjacent strings, and basically diatonic. So for those, learning the appropriate scale in thirds will help. Those on the same frets can be played either with the same finger, of preferrably, two fingers, quite easy to find and execute.
That just leaves the fourths, as in bars 2, 3 and 8 (the 1st 'bar' is an anacrucis) and for those, I'd practise playing them as I go along playing only one note at a time. Bearing in mind  which finger I'm going to play each one with eventually.
Good luck with it. It took Mozart a while to do it, too! And no need to play it as fast as he hoped. Start slow (but in time) and work upwards.

Thanks for the answer. I feel a bit more comfortable playing the second and fourth double notes with index and middle fingers. Is it fine?

You can use whichever fingers you are most comfortable with, bearing in mind where you've come from, and where you're going fret/string-wise.
